# I'd like to make my website's sidebar a reusable component, but I'm not sure how

Tags: reactjs, web-component, blogs, reusability

I have a blog with many pages, and more are being added all the time because it's still under construction. The sidebar changes frequently, and manually modifying all of the sidebars for all of the pages is tedious.

I have yet to learn more about coding, and I have no idea how to create reusable components. I read about it online and tried various things with react, but what I did didn't work.
Here is the code for sidebar:

```
<td class="col1">

            <h3 style="font-variant: small-caps; font-weight:bold; color: #5C331B;">&nbspArt&nbsp</h3>

             <p>
              <a style="display: block;" href="Theodor Kittelsen.html">&nbspTheodor Kittelsen&nbsp</a>
             </p>
             <p>
              <a style="display: block;" href="Eilif Peterssen.html">&nbspEilif Peterssen&nbsp</a>
             </p>
             <p>
              <a style="display: block;" href="Mikhail Nesterov.html">&nbspMikhail Nesterov&nbsp</a>
             </p>
             <p>
              <a style="display: block;" href="Caspar David Friedrich.html">&nbspCaspar David Friedrich&nbsp</a>
             </p>
             <p>
              <a style="display: block;" href="Hans Thoma.html">&nbspHans Thoma&nbsp</a>
             </p>
             <p>
              <a style="display: block;" href="George Inness.html">&nbspGeorge Inness&nbsp</a>
             </p>

             <h3 style="font-variant: small-caps; font-weight:bold; color: #5C331B;">&nbspPoetry&nbsp</h3> 
            
             <p>
              <a style="display: block;" href="PERCY BYSSHE SHELLEY.html">&nbspPercy Bysshe Shelley&nbsp</a>
             </p>
             <p>
              <a style="display: block;" href="ALGERNON CHARLES SWINBURNE.html">&nbspAlgernon Charles Swinburne&nbsp</a>
             </p>
             <p>
              <a style="display: block;" href="Rainer Maria Rilke.html">&nbspRainer Maria Rilke&nbsp</a>
             </p>
             <p>
              <a style="display: block;" href="LORD TENNYSON.html">&nbspLord Tennyson&nbsp</a>
             </p>
             <p>
              <a style="display: block;" href="Thomas Stearns Eliot.html">&nbspThomas Stearns Eliot&nbsp</a>
             </p>
             <p>
              <a style="display: block;" href="John Keats.html">&nbspJohn Keats&nbsp</a>
             </p>
             <p>
              <a style="display: block;" href="William Wordsworth.html">&nbspWilliam Wordsworth&nbsp</a>
             </p>
             <p>
              <a style="display: block;" href="William Blake.html">&nbspWilliam Blake&nbsp</a>
             </p>
             <p>
              <a style="display: block;" href="Johann Wolfgang von Goethe.html">&nbspJohann Wolfgang von Goethe&nbsp</a>
             </p>
             <p>
              <a style="display: block;" href="William Butler Yeats.html">&nbspWilliam Butler Yeats&nbsp</a>
             </p>
             <p>
              <a style="display: block;" href="Ovid.html">&nbspOvid&nbsp</a>
             </p>
             <p>
              <a style="display: block;" href="Mixed.html">&nbspMixed&nbsp</a>
             </p>

             <h3 style="font-variant: small-caps; font-weight:bold; color: #5C331B;">&nbspMusıc&nbsp</h3>

             <p>
              <a style="display: block;" href="Tenhi.html">&nbspTenhi&nbsp</a>
             </p>
             <p>
              <a style="display: block;" href="Empyrium.html">&nbspEmpyrium&nbsp</a>
             </p>
             <p>
              <a style="display: block;" href="Ulver.html">&nbspUlver&nbsp</a>
             </p>
             <p>
              <a style="display: block;" href="Öröm.html">&nbspÖröm&nbsp</a>
             </p>
             <p>
              <a style="display: block;" href="Savall.html">&nbspJordi & Arianna Savall&nbsp</a>
             </p>


             <div class="box" style="background-color: #7d9ea2f4; padding: 2px; border-width: 1px; border-color: rgb(175, 164, 157); border-style: solid;">
              <p>
              <img src="PinIt.png" alt="Pin it button" height="20px" width="23px">
              <a href="" data-pin-do="buttonPin" data-pin-shape="round">Pin this page for later</a>
              </p>
    
    
              <p>
                <img src="envelope.png" alt="Email icon" style="margin-right: 2px; margin-bottom: 2px; height: 20px; width: 26px;">
                <a href="mailto:?" data-pin-do="buttonPin" data-pin-shape="round">Email yourself this page</a>
    
              </p>
               <p>
                  <img src="pinterest-icon.png" alt="pinterest logo" style="margin-top: 2px; margin-right:12px; margin-bottom: 20px; height: 25px; width: 25px; float: left">
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <a href="https://tr.pinterest.com/cerenntubaa/" data-pin-do="buttonPin" data-pin-shape="round">Pinterest Boards</a>
                  </p>
              </div>

            </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi first create an array of object which u pass the data to sidebar component

```
[
  {
     href: ....
     text: ....
  }
]
```

Then you can map this array of objects

```
 {dataSet.map((element, index) => {
            return <p>
                      <a style="display: block;" href=data.html>{data.text}</a>
                  </p>
          })}
```

I guess this will cover your problem